# Lookup with Row and Column Criteria from Table with the Row+Column criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to merge the data of 2 sheets together.

Sheet 1 Columns

```
Unique_ID
C1
C2
C3
...
```

Sheet 2 Columns

```
Unique ID
Type [List of C1, C2, C3... etc. which matches the column headers in Sheet 1]
Answer
```

I need to bring in "Answer" from Sheet 2 into Sheet 1. So the logic would have to be:

Sheet 1 Unique_ID = Sheet 2 Unique ID

AND

Sheet 1 Column Header[C1, C2, C3... etc.] = Sheet 2 [List of C1, C2, C3... etc.]

Please let me know if that doesn't make sense!

Sheet 1 - Table 1

```
Unique ID   C1  C2  C3
1           
2           
3
```

Sheet 2 - Table 2

```
Unique ID   Type    Answer
1            C1 Text1
1            C2 Text2
1            C3 Text3
2            C1 Text4
2            C2 Text5
2            C3 Text6
3            C1 Text7
3            C2 Text8
3            C3 Text9
```

Sheet 1 - Table 1
Expected Results

```
Unique ID   C1     C2     C3
1          Text1    Text2   Text3
2          Text4    Text5   Text6
3          Text7    Text8   Text9
```

I got it to work by concatenating the Unique_ID and the column header to make a unique key in Sheet 2 which is Column3. In Sheet 1, I did

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($A2,B$1),Table2[[#All],[Column3]:[Answer]])
```

Is there a way to do this without breaking my table into a range and without adding an extra column in Sheet 2? I was trying to do use `INDEX` and `MATCH`, but I could not quite figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Index/Match combo for this goes like this, starting in B2 in Sheet1, Row 1 has labels. Assuming that table in Sheet2 starts in A1.

```
=index(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$100,match($A2&B$1,index(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100,0),0))
```

Copy across and down.

You don't want to use whole columns with this type of formula, because it may slow down the workbook. Reference only the ranges with data.

[image]